# DataSet ToList method returns empty List, even though it has elements

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Sorry if somebody has already asked this question. I've been looking around but couldn't find anything related.

So, I am using Entity Framework and I am trying to load the list of "Idiomas" from the dataset using the ToList method through the following code:

```
//List<Idioma> ans = new List<Idioma>(contexto.Idiomas);
return contexto.Idiomas.ToList();
```

However, the method is returning an empty list, even though I can see through the debugger that the DataSet has elements.

**EDIT**

I have not put any extra code because there is not any extra code besides those two lines.
I just create a Entity Framework model-first, generated the database, and updated the model from the database to make sure everything was ok.

Contexto is a instance from the class LivroContexto, which implements DbContext (auto generated by vs2012, see below).

LivroContainer:

```
public partial class LivroContainer : DbContext
{
    public LivroContainer() : base("name=LivroContainer")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Idioma> Idiomas { get; set; }
}
```

Idiomas:

```
public partial class Idioma
{
    public Idioma()
    {
        this.Traducaos = new HashSet<Traducao>();
    }

    public int IdIdioma { get; set; }
    public string Lingua { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Traducao> Traducaos { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can u please post definition of "contexto" and a definition of the type of "contexto"?

Comment: Contexto in this case is the auto generated container for the entity framework (generated through the edmx file in vs2012).

Comment: Assuming that you are indeed using the Entity Framework, that `contexto` is your object context, and Idiomas is a property encapsulating a table or view, this sounds impossible. Then again, in the assumed scenario, there wouldn't be any DataSets, certainly not any that have elements.

Comment: I edit my questions with full code to the context and idioma classes. I have added the items myself. and I can see in the debugger the DbSet holds the added items, but they are not added to the the list in the ToList method.

Comment: Is `IdIdioma` marked a primary key in the edmx?

Comment: this is an old thread, but something I have experienced twice in the last few days, so I though I should share my thoughts: Make sure you check that your connection string is configured correctly. If you specify a key in the Context contructor, and the key is not present in web.config, EF will use a local default database, and not your SQL server. Tables will also be created and all you get is empty sets.

Answer (score 0):

nobody can see, why your code is not working, from the amount of code you have posted.

however, make sure following :

1. the class of the instance `contexto` inherits `DbContext` or any child class inheriting `DbContext`.
2. make sure, in case, you have not generated the database, through the code,rather mapped an existing database, to a codefirst frontend, that `DbSet<Idioma> Idiomas` is mapped to proper table. ie.

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Idioma>().ToTable("IdiomaTableNameInDatabase");
   }
   ```
3. make sure, your connectionString name, that you passed in the DbContext base constructor is present in the web.config, and if you have not passed anything, make sure a connectionString with the name of your DbContext inheriting class is there.

If all these are correct, there is absolutely no reason, why `contexto.Idiomas.ToList()` won't return anything.

and also, say, your context class is MyContext, then it should be like this:

```
public class MyContext:DbContext
{
     public MyContext:base("ConnectionStringName")
     {
     }

     //--dbSet properties
     public DbSet<Idioma> Idiomas{get;set;}

     //other overridden methods
}
```

which you use, on your upper layers like this:

```
public List<Idioma> GetAllIdiomas()
{
   MyContext contexto = new MyContext();
   return contexto.Idiomas.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I have update the question with full code. I didn't post before because all of the lower layer was autogenerated by vs2012. Only thing I added was the add function (which works perfectly fine) and the read function (the problem).

Comment: please remove this line from onModelCreating method `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();`

Comment: try putting this `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)`; in your onModelCreating and also remove that partial from both your context and the entity class, and see it works

Comment: Made the changes you suggested, but the behaviour remains.

Comment: so you said, you can see the data in the list when you debug. Is it likely, that somehow, you are not trapping or resetting the data being returned?

Comment: No, I am prrety sure i am not resseting the data. I added the debug right after the ToList method, with nothing else in the enviroment being changed. I am starting to think this is a bug in the language.

Comment: haha, no @Bonet, there is no bug in the language, at least in this scenario, I've been using entityframework on more than a dozen projects, for last two years. Point is, there has to be something, you are missing, some minor mistake, like, there is no data in the table itself or something that silly

Comment: Yeah, i know, I have used in a couple of projects too, but bugs can come from a very specific combination of factors that are one in a million. Luckily I am in the very start of this one. I will try to reset the database adn recreate the model. Maybe that works.